# Unable to Login as root after mysql service restart

Tags: 14.04, permissions, login, mysql

I installed mysql on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS like:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

after completely removing mysql with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo deluser mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Everything works fine until I restart the mysql service with:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

**Then I can no longer login with the root user and password.** I get the error access denied for root@localhost using password yes

My only guess: is it possible there are two instances of mysql installed?

**edit**

---

All of the below are set as `install`from the output of:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep "mysql"

libapache2-mod-auth-mysql
libdbd-mysql-perl
libmysqlclient18:amd64
libmysqlcppconn7
mysql-client-5.5
mysql-client-core-5.5
mysql-common
mysql-server
mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server-core-5.5
mysql-utilities
mysql-workbench
mysql-workbench-data
php5-mysql
python-mysql.connector
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions to set a root password during the reinstall? if not, you can run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` at any time to do so.

Comment: I was prompted to add a root password, which worked once it was installed before the restart.

Comment: Post the output for `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep "mysql"`. Only possible way to see whether any other instance matching **mysql**. Meanwhile try `mysql -u username -p` & then type the password when it prompts.

Comment: post updated @AzkerM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to reset mysql root password:

Change my.cnf configuration file:

```
[mysqld]

skip-grant-tables
```

Restart service, and login with root without password, then change the root password:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('your_new_password');
```

Remove `skip-grant-tables` entry from my.cnf and restart mysql.

Comment: This results in `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement` with mysql 5.5.38.

Comment: If you try with: `UPDATE mysql.user set password = PASSWORD('your_new_password') where user = 'root' and host = 'localhost'`

Comment: I had to be logged in as `root` and not `ubuntu` when starting mysql.

Comment: Also I had to use:
`update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('MyNewPass') where user='root';`

Comment: Change the `ubuntu` password using the same sql.